# Weyl tensor contractions should all vanish

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

Weyl tensor is defined such that all contractions vanish.

When I tried to contract it in 4D with the inverse metric I don't get zero.

$$g^{\rho \sigma}C_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}=R^{\lambda}_{\lambda\mu\nu}+1/6[g_{\nu\mu}-g_{\mu\nu}]R+1/2[R_{\nu\mu}-R_{\mu\nu}]-1/2[R_{\nu\mu}-R_{\mu\nu}]$$

$$g^{\rho \sigma}C_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}=R^{\lambda}_{\lambda\mu\nu}= R_{\mu\nu}\neq0.$$

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the definition of the Weyl tensor, we have:

$C_{abcd} = R_{abcd} + \frac{1}{2}\left(g_{ad}R_{cb} + g_{bc}R_{da} - g_{ac}R_{db} - g_{bd}R_{ca}\right) + \frac{1}{6} \left(g_{ac} g_{db} - g_{ad}g_{cb}\right)R$

and now contracting over $a$ and $c$, we obtain:

$C^{a}_{bad} = R^{a}_{bad} + \frac{1}{2} \left(g^{a}_{d} R_{ab} + g_{ba}R_{d}^{a} - g^{a}_{a}R_{db} - g_{bd}R_{a}^{a}\right) + \frac{1}{6} \left(g^{a}_{a} g_{db} - g^{a}_{d}g_{ab}\right)R$

$= R^{a}_{bad} + \frac{1}{2} \left(R_{db} + R_{bd} - 4R_{db} - g_{bd}R\right) + \frac{1}{6} \left(4 g_{db} - g_{bd}\right)R$

$=R^{a}_{bad} + \frac{1}{2} R_{db} + \frac{1}{2}R_{db} - 2R_{db} - \frac{R}{2}g_{bd} + \frac{2}{3}g_{db}R - \frac{R}{6} g_{db}$

$=-\frac{R}{2}g_{bd} + \frac{2}{3}g_{db}R - \frac{R}{6} g_{db}$

$=g_{db} \left(-\frac{R}{2} + \frac{2}{3}R - \frac{R}{6}\right)$

$=0$,

as required.

Comment: Thanks. But can we get zero by contacting over $a$ and $b$, this was my question.

Comment: @VictorVMotti Indeed. The Weyl tensor has the special property that contraction over ANY pair of indices will yield zero. I think the mistake that you had was if you look carefully in your 1/6 term, you are missing a Ricci scalar term, which is why I re-wrote the definition from scratch in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but even if adding the Ricci scalar term, which I just did, when unlike you I am contracting over $a$ and $b$ I cannot pick up the trace of the metric twice as you did above. This is my problem here.

Comment: @VictorVMotti Ahh. I see what you're saying. All the terms vanish except the first. Note actually, if you contract on the first two indices, all the terms vanish except the first, which is $R^{a}_{acd}$, but this is NOT the Ricci tensor, since, by definition, the Ricci tensor is obtained by contracting on the first and third indices of Riemann. Indeed, $R^{a}_{acd}$ is zero by the symmetries of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: Perfect answer. All clear now. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @VictorVMotti No problem. It's easy to forget that Ricci is not obtained from any contraction of Riemann!